# We saw URL-decoded PHP code. What does the code mean?

Tags: php

We saw URL-decoded PHP code that will probably try to take down our web servers via overflow attack, but we do not know exactly what it does.

The decoded URL string is:

```
/<?php echo chr(78).chr(69).chr(84).chr(83).chr(80).chr(65).chr(82).chr(75).chr(45).chr(80).chr(72).chr(80).chr(45).chr(48).chr(45).(44353702950 (intval($_GET[997])*4567)).chr(45) ?>
```

I tried converting the string and ended up with:

```
NETSPARK-PHP-0-0-
```

Answer (score 2):

It is  testing payload for code injection bug by the tool netsparker. Someone might have started the tool on your site to test for PHP code injection.

As can be simulated on writephponline.com :-

```
url: http://www.writephponline.com/?997=7876876
```

payload:-

```
echo chr(78).chr(69).chr(84).chr(83).chr(80).chr(65).chr(82).chr(75).chr(45).chr(80).chr(72).chr(80).chr(45).chr(48).chr(45).(44353702950*(intval($_GET[997])*4567)).chr(45);
```